# I'm designing a multiple choice questionnaire whose options change based on the choices you've made. Does such a thing exist?

Tags: database, game-engine, survey

The idea is this:

You are creating a character for a fantasy adventure game. The program will ask you a series of questions in order to establish a backstory. How you answer any given question will affect your available options in the ones that follow, dynamically.

The questions are multiple choice, always presented as a list of 5 options.
    In reality there are far more than 5 options, but the program shows you only this subset, selected at random from among the pool. This is to improve replayability and prevent analysis paralysis. 
    Each choice you make may also add unique options to future questions and/or remove others if they become incompatible.

I have a rough idea of how do this. I would organize all the answers into datasets, including a number of tags for each entry that the program could check.
So, for example, if this were a Lord of the Rings game and I chose Dwarf as my race, when I go to select a hometown the program would see the tag "isDwarf" and know to add "Mining Town" to the pool, but perhaps remove "Forest Heart" from the pool. 
In this way it would play kind of like a Choose Your Own Adventure game, but instead of behaving like a flowchart it'd be more of a big tangled database.

Once upon a time I attempted to do something like this in Twine by simply using long lists of if then statements, but the amount of data being processed caused it to run very slowly.

Is there another program that a novice user can use to create something like this?

Comment: Are you looking to do this with programming or with a mostly code-free game engine ? If it's the latter, unfortunately this question is off-topic because it doesn't have anything to do with programming or code. If it's the former, basically any language would do the trick, so the question is simply too broad, and you need to narrow it down. Good luck !